# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o" on JSON and Multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array

The AJAX page returns this `JSON` output:

```
{
    "39": {
        "amount": [
            "1503",
            "1443",
            "1383"
        ],
        "account_number": [
            "552247",
            "552247",
            "552247"
        ]
    },
    "40": {
        "amount": [
            "1289",
            "1284",
            "1279"
        ],
        "account_number": [
            "552247",
            "552247",
            "552247"
        ]
    },
    "41": {
        "amount": [
            "57",
            "52",
            "47"
        ],
        "account_number": [
            "552247",
            "552247",
            "552247"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Calling page:**

```
$.ajax({

            url: 'get_bid_details.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {bidIds:bidList_backup},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {

                var arr = $.parseJSON(response); // shows error on this line.

                $.each(arr, function(index,val) {

                                         ...
                                         ...

                    $.each(arr['amount'], function(ind,val) {

                         ...
                                         ...

                    });

                });
            }

        });
```

I dont know what i made mistake. How to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it's already parsed, jQuery does this automatically when you add `json` as the `dataType`, so the answer is to just remove the line with `$.parseJSON` as it's already an object, and parsing it again will produce errors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I removed that line adeneo. Now i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" on $.each function lines.

Comment: And did you change it to `$.each(response, function ...`  as you no longer have an `arr` variable ?

Comment: I have changed in "success: function(arr)".

Comment: And you realize that the second $.each should be `$.each(val['amount'], function ...`